# How to view information admin section?

Tags: module

We have developed custom admin module and i listed the grid view. But not able view the information of particular record.

We have tried , get the blank page

How to do this?

Comment: Yes you need to create a xml file in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/module.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <planner_planner_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="planner" template="planner/planner.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </planner_planner_index>
</layout>  We have added the above layout file. But i got blank screen. Please post any example code.

Comment: planner/planner.phtml this files created and also check permission as well sa naming conventions

Comment: we have checked the permission and naming conventions. All are looking fine.

Comment: this are basic checks now you need to debug module or you need to upload all code in question so we can help you

Comment: Hi Keyul, we develop first magento website, so i cant understand the module development.So Please share us the step by step procedure admin module development.

Comment: You should post some material (code, screenshot, etc.). This question, as-is, is too unclear.